# Print corresponding value in pandas DF row

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

How do I print out entries in a df using a keyword search? I have a legislative database I'm running a list of climate keywords against:

```
climate_key_words = ['climate','gas','coal','greenhouse','carbon monoxide','carbon',\
                     'carbon dioxide','education',\
                     'gas tax','regulation']
```

Here's my for loop:

```
for bill in df.title:
    for word in climate_key_words:
        if word in bill:
            print(bill)
            print(word)
            print(df.state)
            print('------------')
```

When it prints, `df.state` forces everything to print funky:

```
24313    AK
24314    AK
24315    AK
24316    AK
24317    AK
Name: state, Length: 24318, dtype: object
------------
Relating to limitations on food regulations at farms, farmers' markets, and cottage food production operations.
regulation
But when print(df.state) is absent, it looks much nicer:
------------
Higher education; providing for the protection of certain expressive activities.
education
------------
Schools; allowing a school district board of education to amend certain policy to stock inhalers. Effective date. Emergency.
education
------------
```

How can I include df.state (and other values) and have them printed only once?

Ideally, my output should look like this:

```
###bill
###corresponding title
###corresponding state
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print(df.state) is going to print out the column/field 'state'. You presumably want the state associated with that row of the dataframe?

So I would suggest tweaking your approach slightly and doing something like:

```
for row in range(dataframe.shape[0]): #for each row in the dataframe
    for word in keywords:
    if word in dataframe.iloc[row][bill]
        print(dataframe.iloc[row][bill]) #allows you to access values in the df by row,column
        print(dataframe.iloc[row][state])
        print(dataframe.iloc[row][title])
```